# Website is not clickable in Windows XP Internet Explorer 7

Tags: windows-xp, internet-explorer-7

I have installed Windows XP Virtual PC on Windows 7 to test a site that is having issues in IE7 on windows xp - the website loads up but you cannot click on hyperlinks - its like the website has frozen - now is this a browser support issue or OS issue?

Can anyone shed any light on this? Is there any browser tools i can use to spot any problems?

Sorry if i have been too vague - not much else to say really - completely lost.. Maybe this might help a little;

[image: Handy Screenshot]

Any guidance is appreciated

**UPDATE:** I think i know what the problem maybe - its the jQuery UI reference that is causing issues with the site. Has anyone else experienced similar problems? jquery library used was jquery-1.8.0.min.js

Comment: If this issue is on this single website, it sounds like code problem, on the website itself.  The problem itself is pretty clear it even tells you what line the bad code is on.

Comment: @Ramhound line20 if you look at it in notepadd++ it is the meta tag - that is hardly making the site unclickable. It may be the colorbox overlay preventing me from clicking around on the website

Comment: Its still throwing an error which means something isn't right.

Comment: @Ramhound i dont even know where to start looking at this - i've commented out the colorbox js but that doesnt seem to be causing the problem

Comment: If you suspect its a jquery library problem check the compatability list for the version your using. You are not using the current version, try a newer build, and one that isn't the minified, this will require at lot of debugging on your end.  You will need to check the user agent and do something different that what your doing currently.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like a JavaScript Bug

Have you tried IE7 on another Machine, there are installpackages where you can install a lot of IE Versions side by side

[Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ie/testing-multiple-versions-of-ie-on-one-pc)

Comment: IE7 in windows XP is causing issues for others that are accessing this website.

Comment: probably a function calls somethings which IE7 doesn't support or something like that you could install some kind of java script inspector to get more details

Answer (score 0):

I have found what is causing the issue in Windows XP Internet Explorer 7 it is the doc type declaration

```
<!--<!DOCTYPE html>-->

<html>
<head runat="server">

<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE8" >
```

Is there some sort of script available where depending on the OS and browser you are using you can change the doctype??

Is that even possible?

Answer (score -2):

Kindly check same website on other browsers like Firefox or google chrome, If its working finw then upgrade the IE7 to IE8. Also check adobe flash and JRE(JAVA RUN TIME ENVIRONMENT) installed or not.

Comment: I think i know what the problem maybe - its the jQuery UI reference that is causing issues with the site. Has anyone else experienced similar problems? jquery library used was jquery-1.8.0.min.js